# Core Data To Many Peer Relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm writing a Core Data based Cocoa app for recipes.  I have an Ingredient entity, and want to create a ingredientSubstitutes To Many relationship to other Ingredients, but I'm getting errors either when setting the relationship or when saving the store that I can't figure out.  Here's the Entity description:

```
Ingredient
Attributes:
  ingredientName type:String
Relationships:
  ingredientSubstitutes destination:Ingredient inverse:ingredientSubstitutes
```

In my Nib I have 3 array controllers:

- All ingredients AC
- Available substitutes AC
- Selected ingredient substitutes AC

I have 3 table views that each display the contents of these array controllers.  I then have a button to add one ingredient as a subsitute for another, that is bound as follows

```
Button bindings
Target: All Ingredients AC.selection 
        Selector Name: addIngredientSubstitutesObject:
Argument: Available Substitutes AC.seletion
```

With this setup, as soon as I click the add button, the app throws unrecognized selector sent to instance exception: "-[_NSControllerObjectProxy entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance", as if Ingredient doesn't recognize addIngredientSubstitutesObject.  I added a proxy method to make sure that's the selector that's not recognized, and that is indeed the problem.

After trying a bunch of things and getting no where, as an experiment, I then changed the model, so that ingredientSubstitutes has no inverse:

```
Ingredient
Attributes:
  ingredientName type:String
Relationships:
  ingredientSubstitutes destination:Ingredient inverse:*none*
```

When I run this the add is successful, and all the tables update accordingly, but on save, I get a different unrecognized selector and the app throws an exception:

-[_NSControllerObjectProxy _isKindOfEntity:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Any suggestions as to what might be going on?  Am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, this thread helped tip me off: [Core Data Programmatically Adding a to-many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213663/core-data-programmatically-adding-a-to-many-relationship)

Basically, binding the target to the Array Controller's selection meant that the target object  was an Array Controller's *Proxy* object for an Ingredient, not an actual Ingredient, which apparently does not respond to the To Many accessors that Ingredient does.  I solved this by instead implementing a method in the app delegate that gets the actual objects and can use the To Many accessors:

```
- (void)addSubstituteForSelectedIngredient:(OFIngredient *)ingredient
{
  OFIngredient *selectedIngredient = [[self.allIngredientsArrayController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
  OFIngredient *selectedSubstitute = [[self.availableSubsArrayController selectedObjects] objectAtIndex:0];

  [selectedIngredient addIngredientSubsObject:selectedSubstitute];
}
```

Note that NSArrayController's - (id) selection method (which I tried before, as mentioned in the original description) returns a proxy object, so you must use (NSArray *)selectedObjects!